# How to check if index exists in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, runtime-error

I have a for loop for an array where the element may or may not exist:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array[1][1].length; i++) {
    x[array[1][1][i][1]] =
      array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0];
}
```

However, if the element does not exist, it will throw an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading .)" Due to this, I must use an if statement,

```
for (var i = 0; i < array[1][1].length; i++) {
    if(array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0]){  
        x[array[1][1][i][1]] =
          array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this still throws the error if it does not exist because it is being referenced in the if statement. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes, with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: It would be interesting to learn how you use a 9-dimensional data structure.

Comment: @Pointy String theory in Flatland?

Comment: Try `if(array[1][1][i] && array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0]){`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This would not work because array[1][1][i][4][0] could be undefined.

Comment: Then test for the existance of all those that may be undefined. `if(array[1][1][i] && array[1][1][i][4][0] && array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0]){` --- Optionnal chaining does the same but it is easier to read and maintain. ;) --- Now, that still is a solution to fix what looks like a bad data structure usage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). For example,

```
for (var i = 0; i < array[1][1].length; i++) {
    if(array?.[1]?.[1]?.[I]?.[4]?.[0]?.[4]?.[0]?.[2]?.[0]){  
        x[array[1][1][i][1]] =
          array[1][1][i][4][0][4][0][2][0];
    }
}
```

##### ***Edit: My apologies for not adding this earlier, but credit to @Emiel Zuurbier for the idea of optional chaining.***